# Game 四加一 or 四紮 rules or origin unknown

Tags: simplified-characters, traditional-characters

I have read about this variant in the context of weiqi, however, I cannot find anything about it online. It's something about placing a combination of up to four stones as one move, but what about this "加一"？

I believe it has something to do with Omino Go (Teromino Go?), but I do not see anything about this game (apart from English wikipedia) either.

If you know the rules of the game or a source where I can find out more about it, please, assist

Comment: Do you have a link to the Wiki entry?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referencing [Gomoku](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gomoku). "四加一" essentially means "4 + 1", and in Gomoku, the objective is to place 5 tokens in a row to win the game. This game is commonly played using Go pieces on a Go board.